# Difference between Repeat and Recur

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, comparisons

Based on what I read on Oxford Dictionary, it seems that *repeat* is used
to state that the subject of the verb is repeating the object, while
*recur* is used when we want to say that the subject happens more than
once.

For example:

1. He asked her **to repeat*** her question because he couldn’t hear it clearly.
2. This event **has recurred** several times in recent days.

In the second example, can I say, "This event **has *repeated*** several times in recent days"?

And if it’s applicable, could you please explain whether or not both words in the sentence show difference in meaning?

Comment: _Repeat_ can be causative or inchoative, but _recur_ can't be causative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you need an intransitive use doesn't mean you **need** to use *recur*. Events can repeat, or they can be repeated **because** you can repeat them. So *repeat* can be transitive or intransitive, but *recur* can only be intransitive.

But there's something more important to consider. *Repeat* and *recur* are not of the same register. *Repeat* is an order of magnitude more frequent in actual use according to the OED. It has **many** more common uses than *recur* does.

*Recur* is fancier and tends to be found in more formal or technical circumstances like mathematics, or by more careful writers. *Recur* may be replaced by *reoccur* (in older spellings sometimes *re-occur, reöccur*) by speakers and writers who are less comfortable with *recur*.